# How do I stop my IIS App Pool making a request to wpad.mydomain.com?

Tags: performance, iis-6

As part of some performance troubleshooting, I've monitored the slow startup of a "cold" App Pool (one without an active worker process) in IIS.

When using a built-in account, the App Pool starts in sub-second time. When using a custom local account the App Pool takes 30+ seconds to start processing requests.

The service appears to be making requests to `wpad.mydomain.com`, an address it does not have access to, which causes it to wait 30 seconds for a response before eventually timing out. As a workaround, I've added the hostname to the server's hosts file, to direct the traffic to the local machine, which returns much faster (1-2 seconds).

What do I need to do to stop IIS making this request when this identity is used for the App Pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable web proxy automatic detection.

Comment: To clarify, you need to disable automatic proxy detection *for that app pool user account*, so you will need to login as that user and disable it under internet options->connections.